# Is the retentivity of soft iron more than that of steel?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Permanent magnets must have high retentivity and high coercivity and steel is used as one. So it should have higher retentivity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hysteresis** curve helps us to select suitable materials for different purposes.

**Retentivity**: The magnetic field retained even after removing the magnetising field.

**Coercivity**: The strength of the magnetic field (in the opposite direction) required to demagnetise the material.

---

The first image describes the different parts of a Hysteresis curve:

[image: This image clearly shows all the parts of a hysteresis curve]

The second image compares the Hysteresis curve of soft iron with steel:

[image]

---

**Permanent Magnets**:

Should have:

- High coercivity so that the material is not demagnetised easily
- High retentivity so that the *retained* magnetic field is strong

Despite of steel having less retentivity as compared to soft iron core, it is still used for making permanent magnets. This is attributed to the fact that the coercivity of steel is way more than a soft iron core.

Other materials that can be used for making permanent magnets are: Cobalt, Ticonal, Alnico.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, but sketches that compare hysteresis curves not to scale. One should not conclude that retentivity is "slightly lower" in iron.

Comment: How would you recommend I change my answer?

Comment: I upvoted, I have no real quibbles. But in such sketches, especially the coercivity is never to scale; it is orders of magnitude larger for permanent magnets than for weak iron.

Answer (score -2):

steel retains magneto-field longer, iron acquires the field easier but decays sooner

Comment: Can you elaborate?