# Use of soft iron in electromagnets despite having very high retentivity

Tags: magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

so my book states that an electromagnet should not remain a magnet when the electric field is switched off.then why is soft iron core used as an electromagnet?its retentivity is higher even than steel which is used to make a permanent magnet.please answer only on the basis of retentivity and coercivity.

also i know that soft iron having low coercivity is used in induction related machines where a constantly changing AC current is used.i want to know why it doesnt retain the magnetism when the external magnetic field has been switched off,despite having high retentivity

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203262/is-the-retentivity-of-soft-iron-more-than-that-of-steel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft iron is commonly used here because it is easily magnetized, easy to machine, and cheap.

For an AC motor, the magnetic field direction is flipping constantly, so there is no chance of building up a net residual field in its iron parts.